# Class not Registered error in IIS Published WebService

Tags: c#, web-services, com, iis-7, asmx

I'm developing a WebService and i use COM reference (dll file. I add this reference in project). When i run my webservice through VisualStudio, all works fine. But, When i publish the webserver in Local IIS and try executes the webservice, i get the error:

```
"System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {80327130-FFDB-4506-B160-B9F8DB32DFB2} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at WebServiceDA.WebService1..ctor()"
```

I try to register the class in SysWOW64 and System32 folder, but doesn't work.

My Machine is 64 bit, and the COM is 32 bit. But when i change the Plattform target to 'X86' (originally is 'Any CPU') i got the error:

Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Any idea?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Advanced setting of app pool associated with your website. 
[image]

set Enable 32 bit application to true in General section.

This should fix it.

Comment: Works! Thanks a lot!